# How do I write a proper class definition & declaration when a member is a user defined class?

Tags: c++

I have a class defined in a header file:

```
class TempLogger {
private:
    int pin;
    OneWire thermo;

public:
    TempLogger(int);
    float read();
};
```

And a cpp file with:

```
TempLogger::TempLogger(int x) {
    pin = x;
    OneWire thermo(pin);
}
```

My compiler claims "no matching function for call to 'OneWire::OneWire()' pointing at the first line of the CPP file. What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: Did you mean to initialize your member variables in the constructor's member initializer list? Also what's `OneWire` actually?

Comment: Am I required to do that?

Comment: If you want to call `OneWire`s constructor yes.

Comment: Is there a reason or a document online that explains why this is necessary?

Comment: Does `OneWire` have a non-parametric constructor? Also declaring `OneWire thermo(pin);` hides the name of class member.

Comment: Apparently everyone thinks this is a bad question. Is there a way I can improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `OneWire` doesn't have non-parametric constructor, which is tried to be called at `TempLogger` initialization step. You can either write a non-parametric constructor or even better call the parametric one in initialization list:

```
TempLogger::TempLogger(int x):pin(x),thermo(x){}
```

In your code, you are declaring another variable called `thermo` thus hiding your class-member variable.

Comment: You are right. Am I to take this to mean that when the constructor is called it will first initialize the object with the non-parametric constructor and then run the block to assign values and IF there is no non-parametric function it will error? I think my ruby thinking is getting in the way...

Comment: Yes, if you want to use any other constructor than non-parametric, you should specify it on the initialization list. Generally, it is a good practice to always initialize members of your class on an initialization list.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you are definitely doing wrong is in the constructor

```
TempLogger::TempLogger(int x) {
    pin = x;
    OneWire thermo(pin);      //This creates a local object inside the constructor which gets deleted directly after this statement  
}
```

You might want to do this instead :-

```
class TempLogger {
private:
    int pin;
    OneWire *thermo;

public:
    TempLogger(int);
    float read();
};

TempLogger::TempLogger(int x) {
    pin = x;
    thermo = new OneWire(pin);
}
```

Comment: Why a pointer? It's not necessary at all. Look at the other answers.

Comment: Well there are always a thousand ways to solve a programming problem :)

Comment: Well, that's the worst solution for the problem I can imagine :-P.

Comment: I am sorry i work with both C and C++ and keep mixing up both :D